# Boat from Manaus to Leticia: departure days

Tags: brazil, colombia, riverboats, amazon-river

I want to go from Manaus, Brazil to Leticia, Colombia. Are there certain days the boat from Manaus goes to Leticia or is there a boat going everyday?